# How to avoid saving wrong input data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have many same inputs for percentage purposes, each of them working normally if I'm using normal numbers data. If I'm entering wrong erroneous data like letters or other chars its changing to `0`. But it is changing only in screen, data actually catching wrong. For example if I will type `0fsdfsd` into `input` result in screen will be `0` but actual data in input will be `0f`.
  How to save actual data as`0` but not as `0f`?

I'm using `intl` to format data as decimal, and `isNaN` to catch NaN values.

**Input in render()**

```
<input
  name="bonusCategory"
  value={this.toCurrency(category.bonusrate)}
  className="form-control"
  style={{ width: "60px" }}
  type="text"
  onChange={this.inputChanged.bind(this, idx, category.value)}
/>
/>
```

**toCurrency()**

```
toCurrency(number) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ru-RU", {
    style: "decimal"
  });
  let newValue = isNaN(number) ? 0 : number;
  return formatter.format(newValue);
}
```

**inputChanged()**

```
inputChanged = (idx, index, e) => {
  const { categories } = this.state;
  let bonusCategory = e.target.value;
  console.log(bonusCategory);
  if (bonusCategory.length > 3) return;
  categories.forEach(category => {
    category.bonusrate =
      category.value === index ? e.target.value : category.bonusrate;
  });
  this.setState(oldState => {
    const newDisabledButtons = [...oldState.disabledButtons];
    newDisabledButtons[idx] = false;
    return {
      categories,
      isEdit: false,
      inCart: true,
      disabledButtons: newDisabledButtons
    };
  });
};
```

in `console.log` I can see changing data of `bonusCategory` and it shows wrong result.
pen: https://codepen.io/fatdrfrog/pen/rNBXwrW

Comment: Hello @Fatdrfrog.
What does it mean about this?
Maybe it means `event`?

Comment: @Fatdrfrog.  its quite ok for console.log to print the wrong result. because the onChange method is called each time the input value changes. So to combat this you can implement your validation function inside the `onChange` function and not on the `onKeyDown` function.

Comment: please pay attention to using method of params for onChange handler I offered.

Comment: What is `CategoryValidation` doing?

Comment: @ravibagul91 CategoryValidation actually doing nothing, sorry I forgot to delete it, because it confusing the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah. You should update the question. Also your code is seems to be fine. Can you create a codepen for actual issue?

Comment: @harisu as I wrote, onKeyDown doing nothing here. in `value` there is `this.toCurrency()` method, where I'm doing validation. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to properly combat `toCurrency` into `inputChanged`(I tried this, but `return` statement from `toCurrency` makes code after return been ignored)

Comment: @ravibagul91 ok I will create problem similar to mine in codepen and parse it here.

Comment: @ravibagul91 here is my pen - https://codepen.io/fatdrfrog/pen/rNBXwrW

Comment: @Fatdrfrog you are correct the return statement inside toCurrency will break the other execution of the function. Try out the suggestion in my post below lets see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead and allow the toCurrency to for visual effect but change the input change function as follows

```
  inputChanged = (idx, index, e) => {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    //check for the value attribute and either set it to zero or to actual value
    let bonusCategory = isNaN(e.target.value) ? 0 : e.target.value;
    console.log(bonusCategory);
    if (bonusCategory > 999) return;
    categories.forEach(category => {
      category.bonusrate =
        category.value === index ? bonusCategory : category.bonusrate; //note the use of bunus category
    });
    this.setState(oldState => {
      const newDisabledButtons = [...oldState.disabledButtons];
      newDisabledButtons[idx] = false;
      return {
        categories,
        isEdit: false,
        inCart: true,
        disabledButtons: newDisabledButtons
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: thank you, your suggestion works perfectly. There is only few think left, that is close to my problem. The problem is if I will insert value more than 3 digits it displays all 3 digits properly, but forth digit is saving in `console.log`

Comment: @Fatdrfrog in that case you could check if the `bunusCategory> 999` is greater than 999 and not `bonusCategory.length > 3` this is because bunusCategory is a number and not string

Comment: I am supposing the console.log is not important but if it does then you could do   `console.log(bonusCategory > 999 ?  0 :  bonusCategory );`

Comment: seems like it is not working. Unfortunatelly same problem, it shows 4 digits in `console.log`.

Comment: `console.log` itself is not important as you mentioned. It was my stupid mistake that I was calling `console.log` before `.length` check.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some parameters not `event` for the onChange handler, please try this.

```
    inputChanged = (idx, categoryvalue) => (e) => {
    ... ... ...
    };
```

Comment: No need to do this,  `inputChanged` definition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use input with `type='number'` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number) or parse user input before saving it to `category.bonusrate` (use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` depending on your number format): 
`category.bonusrate = category.value === index ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : category.bonusrate;`

Comment: Thanks for good suggestions, but first one is not an option because I have to think about avoiding mouse scrolling in inputs(probably I will use this option and "freeze"  scrolling in inputs if I will not find better solution). Also, I tried using your second suggestion, but seems, unfortunatelly, it doesn't work.

Comment: May be you can reproduce your problem on CodeSandbox or Codepen?